# How would I go through a text file and pull out the different elements I need?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For part of my programming assignment, I need to write code that takes in a text file name as a command line argument, reads the details of specifically formatted exam questions from the text file and identifies the different features of it. I need it to do this so the program can go on to allow the user to take the exam and answer the questions.

Here is an example of the exam question formatting found in the text file:

```
Question - Multiple
Select all the animals that are mammals:
Possible Answers: 
A. whale
B. dog
C. fish
D. frog
Expected Answer: A, B
Marks: 2
```

I need the program to extract the question type (i.e."Multiple"), the question itself, all possible answers, expected answers, and marks awarded for answering correctly.

The text file also has multiple questions inside of it, separated from one another by a blank line. I am unsure of how to get the program to pick apart the details of each question independent from one another.

**I am not allowed to use any of the following keywords or built-in functions:** for, in  (**contains**()), global, lambda, nonlocal, all(), any(), dir(), eval(), enumerate(), filter(), globals(), locals(), map()

I did try to figure this out for a long while, but I can't seem to understand it. This is currently what I have, although I know it's wildly incorrect. However, it may give some sort of insight into what methods/functions I am allowed to use, so I figured I would add it.

```
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]

fobj = open(filename, 'r')

read_lines = fobj.read()

print(read_lines)

while fobj != "":

    if "Question - " in read_lines:
        question_type = read_lines.split("Question - ")
    break

print(question_type)
```

This doesn't do what it's supposed to at all. I was mostly trying to see if I could just manage to successfully extract the question type and assign it to the question_type variable. However, question_type kept ending up as a list ['', 'Multiple\n'] and I wasn't sure how to fix it.

Comment: You don't have enough information to be able to process the file content. For example... what does a question that is **not** multiple choice look like? It's also unclear what output you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `split(query)` method creates a list by splitting up a string at each occurence of `query`. Splitting the string "Question - Multiple" at the query "Question - " would indeed give you the list of strings you're getting - the first entry is an empty string `''`, and the second entry is the rest of the string `'Multiple\n'`. The `\n` is a newline character, which is likely going to be at the end of each line you read in from the file. You're more or less on the right track.

From here, since splitting at "Question - " will always give you a list that looks like the one you got, you can obtain the question type by taking the second entry in the list. Then you can remove extra whitespace characters (including the newline character `\n`) by using `.strip()`. In your code this would look like:

```py
if "Question - " in read_lines:
    result = read_lines.split("Question - ")
    question_type_raw = result[1]
    question_type = question_type_raw.strip()
    break

print(question_type)
```

You can extract the question type in a single line - this is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```py
import sys
from typing import Optional, TextIO, TypedDict

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Usage: python3 main.py <filename>")
    sys.exit(1)

filename = sys.argv[1]

ParsedObject = TypedDict("ParsedObject", {
    "type": str,
    "question": str,
    "options": list[str],
    "marks": int
})


def parse_question(f: TextIO) -> Optional[ParsedObject]:
    """
    Parses a question from a file.

    Args:
        f: TextIO: File to be parsed from.

    Returns:
        Parsed Object or None if no question was found.
    """
    line = f.readline()

    # If we have reached the end of file
    if line == "":
        return None
    # Get the question type
    q_type = line.strip().split("-")[1]

    # Get the question
    questions: list[str] = []
    for line in f:
        question: str = line.strip()
        # This means we have already read all the questions.
        # Break out of the loop
        if question == "Possible Answers:":
            break
        questions.append(question)

    # Read all the available options
    options: list[str] = []
    for line in f:
        l: str = line.strip()
        # Okay we have read all the options
        # Time for us to break out
        if l.startswith("Expected Answer:"):
            break
        # Get the option and append it.
        option = l.split(maxsplit=1)[1]
        options.append(option)

    # Get the marks
    marks: int = int(f.readline().strip().split(" ")[1])
    # Return the question in `ParsedObject` form
    return {
        "type": q_type,
        "question": "\n".join(questions),
        "options": options,
        "marks": marks
    }


try:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        questions = []
        while True:
            question = parse_question(f)
            if not question:
                break
            questions.append(question)
            f.readline()

    print(questions)

except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File not found")
    sys.exit(1)
```

I have put comments on the code to make you understand what is happening. Good luck! :)